# gremlin.net how to create vertex/edge with id

Tags: c#, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, gremlinnet

I am using latest gremlin.net (3.6.1) and NET 6. I am trying to create vertex/edge, and assign them with existing id, instead of letting server creating id for them.

In gremlin console, this could be done by
g.addV('part').property(id, '59578').

But in C#, this won't get the job done apparently, with property key name of "id". Neptune server always created UUID as id for newly created vertex/edge :(
gtx.AddV("part").Property("id", "59578")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between what you typed in the console and what you submitted in .NET. For .NET you did:

```
Property("id", "59578")
```

and for the console you did:

```
property(id, '59578')
```

As you can seen in the former you chose to make refer to the identifier as a `String` value and in the latter you used `T.id`. `T.id` refers to the identifier of the vertex and `"id"` refers to a property key. In .NET you should be making use of:

```
using static Gremlin.Net.Process.Traversal.T;
```

See other common imports [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-dotnet-imports).